# Finding a formula / sum for the following value table?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given \begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 \style{font-family:inherit}{} 
& \style{font-family:inherit}{} & \style{font-family:inherit}{}\\\hline
 x                                       & 0    & 1   & 2 & 3 &4 &5 &6  & 7\\\hline
 y                                       & 1  & 2 & 4 & 8 & 15 & 26 & 42 & 64\\\hline
\end{array}

it seems so easy, but I can't find a function or a summation formula, which describes these pairs.

I already thought about 
\begin{array}{c} &&&&&&&1 \\
 &&&&&&1 && 1 \\
 &&&&& 1 && 2 && 1 \\
 &&&&1 && 3 && 3 && 1 \\
 &&& 1 && 4 && 6 && 4 && \color{red}{1} \\
 && 1 && 5 && 10 && 10 && \color{red}{5} && \color{red}{1} \\
 & 1 && 6 && 15 && 20 && \color{red}{15} && \color{red}{6} && \color{red}{1} \\
 1 && 7 &&21 && 35 && \color{red}{35} && \color{red}{21}&& \color{red}{7} && \color{red}{1}\end{array}

For instance $26 = 1 + 5 + 10 + 10 $ but the red ones are disturbing. Do you think it works in a similiar way ?

Comment: The [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C4%2C8%2C15%2C26%2C42%2C64&sort=&language=&go=Search) returns two matching sequences: [$A000125$](https://oeis.org/A000125) and [$A129961$](https://oeis.org/A129961).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri : Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A000125), these are cake numbers (maximal number of pieces resulting from $n$ planar cuts through a cube or cake).